# Windows edges sticking together in 21.04 but not in 21.10

Tags: support

I'm using 21.04 and I notice that edges of windows (folders for example) stick together when brought close enough. I noticed that that option is missing in 21.10 by default and I was wondering if there's a way to turn it on? I would really love to switch to 21.10, but missing that options is really annoying to me.

[image]